# Routing redirects twice to component

Tags: angular, typescript

I redirect to another component.

```
this.router.navigate(["book/"+this.organizationKey+"/"+this.projectKey+"/"+this.books[bookIndex].key])
```

All fields have correct value.
When I have the following routes:

```
  { path: 'book/:organizationKey/:projectKey/:bookKey', component: BookComponent},
  { path: 'book/:organizationKey/:projectKey', component: BookComponent},
```

System firstly redirects properly with bookKey variable and a second later again without causing page to reload and show error.

When I comment the second line it works fine, but gives error message:
Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'book/octigo/NNNN'
I checked that ngAfterViewInit is launched twice in the target component, which is of course a problem.

The situation is similar in other areas of my application where I have two types of routes for the same page.

Here is routing for my system

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


import { BookComponent } from './book/book.component';
import { BooklistComponent } from './booklist/booklist.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'landing', pathMatch: 'full' },

  { path: 'book/:organizationKey/:projectKey', component: BookComponent},
  { path: 'book/:organizationKey/:projectKey/:bookKey', component: BookComponent},
  { path: 'booklist/:organizationKey/:projectKey', component: BooklistComponent},

];
```

And here is part of bookcomponent:

```
    constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, public dialog: MatDialog, private router: Router, private service: SharedServiceService, private firestore: FirestoreService) { 
    service.changeIsProjectVisible(true)
    service.changeIsSearchVisible(true)
    service.isChatVisible.subscribe(i => {
      this.isChatVisible = i
    })
    service.changeIsHeaderVisible(true)
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.isLoadingLabelVisible = true
    this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.organizationKey = params['organizationKey']
      this.projectKey = params['projectKey']
      this.bookKey = params['bookKey']
 
      if (this.organizationKey != undefined) {
        this.service.changeOrganization(this.organizationKey)
      }
      if (this.projectKey != undefined) {
        this.service.changeProject(this.projectKey)
      }
      getAuth().onAuthStateChanged(user => { 
        if (user) {
          this.userId = user.uid
          this.firestore.getProjectReadOnlyStatus(this.organizationKey, this.projectKey, this.userId).then(readonly => {
            this.isReadOnly = readonly
          })
        }
        this.getTemplates()
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: can you try to reorder the routes and see its working or not

Comment: Make sure that each route pattern is unique and does not match multiple URLs. In your case, you have two routes with similar patterns ('book/:organizationKey/:projectKey/:bookKey' and 'book/:organizationKey/:projectKey'). Try to make them more specific to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: The configuration is pretty trivial, so if something causes a second navigation it might be out of the code you linked, could you share the code of BookComponent and the whole routing configuration?

Comment: I tried to change the order of router and the problem persisted.

Comment: @akshaysaxena what do you mean by making them specific? And I noticed that when I remove one route the system still tries to do the second round. This is why I got an error then: cannot match any routes.

Answer (score 0):

I finally have found it.
Here is the corrected line of code:

```
  if (this.service.currentOrganizationKey != this.organizationKey && this.organizationKey != undefined) {
    this.service.changeOrganization(this.organizationKey)
  }
  if (this.service.currentProjectKey != this.projectKey && this.projectKey != undefined) {
    this.service.changeProject(this.projectKey)
  }
```

The problem was that immediately after routing I was updating organizationKey and projectKey even if they didn't need to be updated. On each page there is headerComponent which is listening to changes of these two variables. When header received signal that they were changed something strange happend and route was done twice. After adding additional condition, the problem dissappeared.